# Magento event sales_order_invoice_register is called multiple times

Tags: magento

I'm trying to *observe* the event `sales_order_invoice_register` because I need to send some custom emails once an invoice is created.

On some of the invoiced orders I've received the email (sent by my observer) multiple times.

Is it possible for the `register` function from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` to be called multiple times for the same order which has only one invoice?

If `sales_order_invoice_register` is not the best event to watch for, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a flag on the invoice to say whether or not an email has been sent for it, then update that once you've sent your email

Comment: How do your invoices get created (i.e. through some type of integration, or manually through Magento Admin, etc)?

Comment: Integration with braintree payment module

Comment: Magento Admin makes it possible to send an email to customers when invoices are created. It does this by handling the email sending in the controller action, which you can see in `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController::saveAction()`. So one option would be to observe the controller action of the BrainTree extension which creates an invoice using `controller_action_postdispatch_routeName_controllerName_actionName`. You will have to figure out which routeName, controllerName and actionName is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braintree was creating an order & invoice on every credit card form submit even if the card details were incorrect.

Instead of `sales_order_invoice_register` I've changed the observer to use the event `sales_order_invoice_pay`